# SHR 1 Redundancy

Tags: raid, nas, synology-diskstation

I'm setting up my Synology NAS but I'm doubting between using RAID5 (which I'm familiar with) or using SHR1.

From what I can tell, SHR 1 divides the drives up in smaller portions so you can mix sizes. But what happens if you loose the biggest drive? Do you replace it with the same size? How can no data be lost if the other drives combined are smaller than the drive that goes bad?

My setup would consist of two 2TB wd reds and one 6TB wd green (leftovers from other projects).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, SHR doesn't guarantee that there will be *no* wasted capacity. Rather, it will give you as much usable space as it can without compromising redundancy, in this case 4TB, and upgrading just one drive may be necessary (as opposed to traditional RAID).

As mentioned in the [FAQ](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Storage/What_is_Synology_Hybrid_RAID_SHR):

> you can expand an SHR volume by changing the drives one at a time, and allow the DiskStation Manager to repair the volume. **As soon as enough redundant storage is available,** the SHR volume will expand the usable storage capacity.

This implies that the volume capacity can be less than the total disk capacity.

It seems that SHR1 uses similar space allocation as Btrfs "raid1" and Storage Spaces "mirror", so you might find [this calculator](https://carfax.org.uk/btrfs-usage/) relevant. (SHR2 would be Btrfs "raid1c3" and so on.)